# Mysql Dashboard overwriting client (UUID issues)

Tags: mysql, uuid

I am using the MySQL dashboard and I have 2 servers which are master/slave to each other.

When I create the mysql agent, with a *unique* `UUID`, everything works fine.  The agent connects to dashboard and displays correctly. Except that the hostname isn't honoured from agent.ini.  However when I start the agent on the 2nd server, it overwrites the first one.  The name is the same. The server `UUID` is the same (which is odd given that I manually configured the `UUID`) but it still pulls it from the database and not the INI in the server details. However, the host isn't the same.

In other words instead of having 2 instances, it takes over the previous one.

I disabled `UUID` discovery. I set the `UUID`, but can't seem to find any solution to this.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction before I loose all my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Well darn it! Sometimes thinking two seconds solves it.  Since this is replicated host and I have to replicate mysql database ( don't like to do that, I much prefer just replication needed DB and leave mysql database alone), the inventory was shared between hosts.  Well now this was the issue.

To solve it I recreated the inventory, but simply :'truncate mysql.inventory' and restart the agent on the host.

All is good!